# Positioning titles and pictures for a frontpage

Tags: header-footer, titles, front-matter

I would like to make a frontpage in LaTeX as the one I have made in OpenOffice (attached), i.e. there should be a header for the title of the university, title of the thesis and place for a small picture in the top right. Can I see some examples on how to achieve this most easily?

The attached image only shows the upper half of the front page, the rest is blank.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the package `fancyhdr`. The minimal example is below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % this is the line thickness under the header - 0pt for no line
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % and above the footer

\pagestyle{fancy} % to apply your fancy header and footer

\lhead{University of X\\ {\small Faculty of X}}
\rhead{\includegraphics[height=35pt,keepaspectratio]{noimage}}

\setlength\headheight{40pt} % you might want to modify this number so it does not show overfull boxes, if you have bigger image or more text in the header

\begin{document}

\section*{This is the title of the thesis}
\subsection*{A study on how to make front pages with \LaTeX}

\end{document}
```

You will get:

[image]